# Custom pop up like a picker in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to develop a custom popup that works exactly like a picker. The only difference I am looking out for is that I want a view or page to be in the popup content rather than the basic picker items.

Comment: pls share your requirements clearly

Comment: I'm flagging to close your question because it's out of our site scope, it's considered an off- topic (visit [help/on-topic] to know more). But it seems you're looking for something like [a popup page](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked Rg.Plugins.Popup ?
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

You can create your own pages and choose where and how they will popup. Animations ,click to close, timeout closing and many other features are supported.

Comment: Thank you. Serves my purpose.